# Dashcode user guide application

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I was working on dashcode application (Dual product web application)i have mention a URL (http://www.apple.com/trailers/home/xml/current.xml).after running the application i am getting an error "trailers/home/xml/current.xmlFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" So is any other URL which can i use instead of that URL. Or how can i sort out that error? Please help me in this regards.

Thank you
Prince

Answer (score 1):

instead of the given URL (http://www.apple.com/trailers/home/xml/current.xml),use this URL http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/home/xml/current.xml.